# Proof for recurrence relation of laguerre polynomials

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

How can I prove the following recurrence relation for Laguerre polynomials.
$$
(n+1)L_{n+1}(x)=(2n+1-x)L_n(x)-nL_{n-1}(x)
$$
please help me. thanks

Comment: Are you allowed to use Rodrigues formula ? If yes, look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici-Yes, Im allowed to use Rodrigues formula. I visited the site youve given me, but still, I dont know how to prove the recurrence relation on my own. Pls help me prove it. I need it in my thesis... Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before speaking about Rodrigues formula, you can use the closed for of Laguerre polynomials which is
L[n] = Sum[ Binomial[n,k] (-x)^k / k! , {k,0,n} ]
If you start with L[n+1] and expand it, you will arrive to the recurrence relation.

You can also prove it by induction starting with the first terms.

More serious help will be found at http://aw.twi.tudelft.nl/~koekoek/documents/thesis.pdf. This also can help you : https://www.math.lsu.edu/system/files/MD1%20Paper.pdf

I wonder if proper manipulation of Rodrigues formula would not be easier.

Comment: got it. thanks...

Comment: @GlenioRosario. If you like this answer, you can accept it in order other people know that it could be useful. Cheers.

Comment: How? I dunno how to accept it.